# Create new dictionary with values as lists and non-empty keys

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, concatenation

How can I concat values to empty keys.

```
my_array = 
[('Schedule: ', '231xxx'),
 ('Name(s): ', 'K, KEN '),
 (' ', 'K, CHRISTINA '),
 ('Address: ', '5xx 4TH LN ANYTOWN CO 81xxx-'),
 ('Description: ', 'BEG PT FT N OF COR OF SEC TH N 85 DEG 11 MIN'),
 ('  ', 'W 100.00 FT TH N'),
 ('  ', 'S 45 DEG 08 MIN E '),
 ('  ', '194.00 FT TO ')
]
```

Desired result would be:

```
dict { ('Schedule: ', '231xxx'),
 ('Name(s): ', 'K, KEN ',  'K, CHRISTINA '),
 ('Address: ', '5xx 4TH LN ANYTOWN CO 81xxx-'),
 ('Description: ', 'BEG PT FT N OF COR OF SEC TH N 85 DEG 11 MIN' W 100.00 FT TH N' S 45 DEG 08 MIN E 194.00 FT TO ')}
```

Comment: What are your rules for concatenation? Your "desired result" is not valid syntax, and some of the piece that are would not work as dictionary elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood you right. This script will create new dictionary with values as lists and non-empty keys:

```
array = [('Schedule: ', '231xxx'),
 ('Name(s): ', 'K, KEN '),
 (' ', 'K, CHRISTINA '),
 ('Address: ', '5xx 4TH LN ANYTOWN CO 81xxx-'),
 ('Description: ', 'BEG PT FT N OF COR OF SEC TH N 85 DEG 11 MIN'),
 ('  ', 'W 100.00 FT TH N'),
 ('  ', 'S 45 DEG 08 MIN E '),
 ('  ', '194.00 FT TO ')
]

out = {}
last_key = ''
for k, v in array:
    if k.strip():
        last_key = k
    out.setdefault(last_key, []).append(v)


from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Address:': ['5xx 4TH LN ANYTOWN CO 81xxx-'],
 'Description:': ['BEG PT FT N OF COR OF SEC TH N 85 DEG 11 MIN',
                  'W 100.00 FT TH N',
                  'S 45 DEG 08 MIN E ',
                  '194.00 FT TO '],
 'Name(s):': ['K, KEN ', 'K, CHRISTINA '],
 'Schedule:': ['231xxx']}
```